# SQL Selecting record with highest ID

Tags: sql, pervasive

I have a issue with some SQL that I can't wrap my head around a solution.

Right now the query I am running basically is:

```
SELECT Q.ID, Q.STATUS, C.LASTNAME, C.FIRSTNAME, 
       C.POSTAL, C.PHONE 
FROM QUEUE Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON Q.ID = C.APPID 
WHERE C.LASTNAME LIKE 'SMITH%'
```

I have about 200 records from this query. My issue is the same person has multiple occurances.

```
Q.ID  Q.STATUS   C.LASTNAME   C.FIRSTNAME   ETC...
 1        A         SMITH        JOHN
 2        A         SMITH        RYAN
 3        B         SMITH        BRIAN
 100      A         SMITH        RYAN
 200      A         SMITH        RYAN
```

What I need returned instead is

```
Q.ID   Q.STATUS   C.LASTNAME   C.FIRSTNAME   ETC...
 1        A          SMITH         JOHN
 3        B          SMITH         BRIAN
 200      A          SMITH         RYAN
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please. I have tried

```
SELECT WHATEVER FROM TABLE WHERE Q.ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE BLAH BLAH)
```

which worked when searching for "RYAN SMITH" specifically. But I need to show all results for SMITH with the highest IDs.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Which flavor of SQL?? MySQL, SLQ Server, Oracle etc. ?

Comment: So, for a given first name and last name, you want the largest id?

Comment: Guess that would help a bit...Pervasive v9.5..and yes they can search by lastname or first name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do something like below

```
SELECT WHATEVER FROM TABLE 
WHERE Q.ID IN 
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE 
     WHERE BLAH...BLAH 
     GROUP BY C.FIRSTNAME, C.LASTNAME)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like that? well it is not really a SQL statement, just showing the idea

```
select * from Table where id in (
         select max(q.id) from Table group by c.lastname, c,firstname
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `CUSTOMER.ID`, and I think I'm right, here it goes:

```
SELECT Q.ID, Q.STATUS, M.LASTNAME, M.FIRSTNAME, 
       M.POSTAL, M.PHONE 
FROM QUEUE Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT C2.ID CID, 
         MAX(C2.FIRSTNAME) FIRSTNAME, 
         MAX(C2.LASTNAME) LASTNAME, 
         MAX(C2.POSTAL) POSTAL,
         MAX(C2.PHONE) PHONE,
         MAX(Q2.ID) QID
  FROM QUEUE Q2 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER C2 ON Q2.ID = C.APPID 
  WHERE C2.LASTNAME LIKE 'SMITH%'
  GROUP BY C2.ID
) M ON (M.QID = Q.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, this should work:

```
SELECT Q.ID
     , Q.STATUS
     , C.LASTNAME
     , C.FIRSTNAME, 
     , C.POSTAL
     , C.PHONE
  FROM QUEUE Q 
  join CUSTOMER C ON Q.ID = C.APPID 
 WHERE C.LASTNAME like 'SMITH%'
   and not exists (SELECT *
                     FROM CUSTOMER innerCustomer
                    WHERE innerCustomer.LASTNAME like 'SMITH%'
                      and innerCustomer.APPID > C.APPID
                  )
```

Note: I have change "left join" by "inner join" because you are filtering per C.LASTNAME. So I think left join doesn't have many sense.